# Upgrading mvc 4.0

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, upgrade

I really need at least mvc 4.3 **for my project** because of migrations, but cannot find any tutorial or tool. What could be the steps to take and what to download, install, execute?

Comment: Are you talking about MVC or Entity Framework?  Entity Framework introduced migrations around that point.

Comment: I probably must have confused those two things. If you say so - then EF. My project has mvc and code first models which are just simple classes.

Comment: Since neither MVC nor EF upgrades are listed in nuget package upgrade list, I really don't know where to start :/

Comment: Did you work code first? Just install EF 5 through Nuget and test if everything still works. There have been some changes in configuration and mapping if I remember well.

Comment: For some reason it wasn't showing EF5 in my upgrade list. However, when I selected pre-released versions too, it offered me 6.0-alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment I assume you are referring to Entity Framework.

If you are currently using EF 4.x (where x < 3) in your project and you want to use the latest version of Entity Framework, you can simply update Entity Framework using the NuGet package manager.  Most projects will upgrade smoothly (all of mine did).

You may wish to search the web and/or stack overflow for "upgrade entity framework 4 to 5" to identify edge cases that may apply to you.

Make sure you have checked everything into source control before doing the upgrade so that you can easily recover if something does go wrong.

NOTE: Your comment says that EF is not listed in the NuGet upgrade list.  If you are not on EF 5, it should be listed.  You can start an upgrade from the package manager command line by entering:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0
```

If that produces any error messages, suggest you open a new question with the errors it lists.

Comment: When it comes to configurations and installations, I am definitely not the right person to chose :( On the other hand, I find (whatever I am using haha) a very nice way of reaching my goal (= a nice working website). Thanks for help :)